# Choosing curves in data fitting

Tags: experimental-physics, data-analysis

I have got a series of data points in experiments. And now I am trying to do some fitting job. What kind of curve should I select for this if I don't know what the exact expression is?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a fit? If it is to make a pretty line to draw through the data points that is one thing. If it is to understand your results, than the focus should be on the physics of what is happening, not on how fits to random curves look. A 'good' fit to an unphysical function is useless (and usually worse than useless since you start to mislead yourself).

Comment: @JonCuster i would interpret this question as asking for general fitting methods (see also my answer).

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15469/

Comment: @JonCuster: While I do agree with you 100% that it's always preferable to have a physics model for what we are fitting, there are areas in which we do not follow that rule. The fits to e.g. thermocouple voltages as a function of temperature are often just polynomials to make the engineering implementation easier. I think the same is true for optical indices of refraction for glass and lenses. The reason is, of course, because we aren't trying to explain the physics of thermocouples and optical glass, we just want to use them. I doubt, though, that the OP's problem is in this category.

Comment: You should tell is what your problem is. There is no general answer to what you "should" be doing, but there are very specific answers as to what you should not be doing, depending on the problem. As Jon Custer correctly pointed out, it's very important to avoid those pitfalls (like..."making data look pretty" is almost always a bad, bad, bad idea).

Comment: @JonCuster Well, thanks for your reply. But I am not trying to have a pretty fit. For instance, I have to find out the peak of the curve when the expression is unknown. Is it necessary to establish a model for this circumstance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics; curve-fitting is either compatible with Cross-Validated or Math SE.

Comment: HOw can you find the peak of the curve is you don't know the physical basis of the data.  You would need to make some kind of assumption about whether the behavior is monotonic  (or not)between adjacent data points.  If the data is from a calibration run of some type and you *know* that the data isn't oscillatory, the curve would serve some type of experimental-behaviorial function. A basic guessing sequence would be linear, power, exponential, polynomial, logarithmic, gaussian, arctan, ...

Answer (score 1):

Fitting in general is not as trivial as is often assumed in undergraduate courses. If you are trying to fit a **specific model** (i.e. an equation describing your data) that only has some **parameters** that you want to optimize one usually linearizes the problem and does a standard linear least squares fit.

What you are talking about is different though, it is a problem of **model comparison**. So instead you have a number of models that all have free parameters and you are trying to find out which of these fits better. This problem can be treated using **Bayesian analysis** and in fact one finds a rigorous probability rule similar to the statement of [*Occam's razor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). A wonderful outline of how to do this can be found in [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Analysis-A-Bayesian-Tutorial/dp/0198568320) gem of a book or in Jayne's [textbook](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Probability_Theory.html?id=tTN4HuUNXjgC&redir_esc=y) on probability theory.